# Micronaut queryConfigEnabled

Tags: swagger-ui, micronaut, micronaut-openapi

I would like to activate the *queryConfigEnabled* swagger-ui property.

Is there a way to do that? Maybe in the openapi.properties or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle with java, you can try this one:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.fork = true
    options.forkOptions.jvmArgs << '-Dmicronaut.openapi.views.spec=rapidoc.enabled=true,swagger-ui.enabled=true,swagger-ui.theme=flattop,swagger-ui.queryConfigEnabled=true'

    ...
}
```

So you can try to add `swagger-ui.queryConfigEnabled=true` to the end of jvmArgs

Comment: It doesn’t work. Micronaut openapi doesn’t read this property. [see source code](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-openapi/blob/master/openapi/src/main/java/io/micronaut/openapi/view/SwaggerUIConfig.java)